# Tumblr C# Access token oauth_signature does not match expected value 401 Error

Tags: .net, oauth, tumblr

I am working on a .net app to gain access to my tumblr account.

In the ouath handshake I am making it through the authorization step. However when trying to get my access tokens (after I authorize my account on tumblr to grant my app permissions) I am getting a 401 error of oauth_signature does not match expected value

Here is my url I am calling to get the access token… is there something wrong with this format? (I put some z’s in for my consumer key, oauth token, and oauth verifier for privacy purposes). This is the same format I use for twitter which works fine.

Any Ideas?

http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=UDwa2ZMvBGU53XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_nonce=9299949&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1345645132&oauth_token=kg6M3FeYUoHVEMRQZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ&oauth_verifier=BgXcqcmyiSuJWHggMzCQcZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=iPbc5kE5LbudXJm1MVc0VNeIQxA%3D

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the oauth token secret gotten during the step setting up the URL for request for authorization needs to also be saved off and then used in the final step gaining the access token and secret.

Comment: Thank you, i have same problem with tumblr (twitter works fine) but i dont understand what you mean. Can you explait it more clear?

Comment: On the step to get authorization you need to save off the token secret that comes back on the querystring. Then on final step to get the final token and token secret which gives your app access to tumblr functionality use that initial token secret when generating that URL request. The code is on my other comp. I'll post an example.

Comment: I´m having similar trouble. I got a working twitter implementation, which i tried to clone for tumblr. First steps work okay, but when I try to verify the token I get a 401. I didn´t include the oauth_token_secret, where should I put this? Do you still have the example you mentioned?

Comment: Since Comments are made in 2012 and 2015 Can someone explain for latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extract the oauth_token_secret after performing the call to

```
https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token
```

Params for the second call:

```
$params = array(
            "oauth_consumer_key" => $this->key,
            "oauth_nonce" => time(),
            "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
            "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
            "oauth_token" => $tumblr_oauth_token,
            "oauth_verifier" => $oauth_verifier,
            "oauth_version" => "1.0",
        );
```

And then use the `token_secret` for `oauth_signature`:

```
$secret = encode_rfc3986($token)."&".encode_rfc3986($token_secret);
$params['oauth_signature']=encode_rfc3986(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$baseString, $secret, TRUE)));
```

All done. The issue occurred due to `oauth_signature`.